# I defined a search path, but files in otrher folders are being searched

Tags: python, regex, path

Can someone PLEASE tell me why the below code is searching for sub folders in the specified path. I only want all .txt and .log files in c:\Python27 to be searched. But the search is showing results for .txt and .log file in c:\Python27\Doc ... so on and so forth as well. Thanks.

```
elif searchType =='3':
          print "Directory to be searched: c:\Python27 "
          print " "
          directory = os.path.join("c:\\","Python27")
          regex = re.compile(r'3[0-9]\d{10}')
          for root,dirname, files in os.walk(directory):
             for file in files:
               if file.endswith(".log") or file.endswith(".txt"):
                  f=open(os.path.join(root,file))
                  for line in f.readlines():
                      searchedstr = regex.findall(line)
                      for word in searchedstr:
                         print "String found: " + word
                         print "File: " + os.path.join(root,file)
                         break
                         f.close()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`os.walk` is *recursive* directory walking - its documentation says:

> Generate the file names in a directory
>   tree by walking the tree either
>   top-down or bottom-up.

So you get what you ask for ;-)

If you don't need recursion, just use `os.listdir` instead. Since `os.walk` by default walks top-down you could also cut the loop after the first directory, but it's cumbersome. `os.listdir` is simple:

```
>>> for filename in  os.listdir(r"c:\python26\\"):
...   if filename.endswith('.txt') or filename.endswith('.log'): print filename
... 
lxml-wininst.log
MySQL-python-wininst.log
py2exe-wininst.log
PyXML-wininst.log
scons-wininst.log
```